# iOS UITabBarController created programmatically is not displaying its "More" navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I want to create an iOS UITabBarController with 6 child view controllers, which is just enough children to cause the "More" tab to appear on iPhone 11 Pro Max in portrait orientation.  As an experiment I'd like to do this programmatically in Swift, without making any modification to the Main.storyboard file of my Xcode project.  The following is my entire ViewController.swift file, using the default "Single View App" Xcode 11.5 on macOS Catalina 10.15.4.

```
import UIKit;

class ViewController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        struct Band {
            let badge: String;
            let color: UIColor;
            let systemItem: UITabBarItem.SystemItem;
        }

        let bands: [Band] = [
            Band(badge: "0", color: .red,    systemItem: .bookmarks),
            Band(badge: "1", color: .orange, systemItem: .contacts),
            Band(badge: "2", color: .yellow, systemItem: .downloads),
            Band(badge: "3", color: .green,  systemItem: .favorites),
            Band(badge: "4", color: .blue,   systemItem: .featured),
            Band(badge: "5", color: .purple, systemItem: .history)
        ];

        let kids: [UIViewController] = bands.map {
            let viewController: UIViewController = UIViewController();
            viewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: $0.systemItem, tag: Int($0.badge)!);
            viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = $0.badge;
            viewController.view.backgroundColor = $0.color;
            return viewController;
        }

        //Make sure all 6 kids are present and okay.
        kids.forEach {print($0.tabBarItem.tag, $0.tabBarItem.badgeValue!);}

        setViewControllers(kids, animated: true);  //Why only getting 4 of 6 in portrait?
        print("viewControllers!.count = \(viewControllers!.count)");
    }
}
```

viewControllers!.count should be 6.  But when I run on the iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator in portrait orientation, viewControllers!.count is 4 and I see tabs for only the first 4 children, with no "More" tab.  (When I run the project on an iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator that is already in landscape orientation, viewControllers!.count is 6 and I see tabs for all 6 children.)  The same thing is happening on my iPhone 8 Plus simulator.  Why am I getting only 4 out of 6 with no "More" in portrait, and is it possible to do what I'm trying to do just by modifying the ViewController.swift file?  Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: Your code seems to be fine, I'm getting 4 + 1more menu with 2 additional menus in more.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this, Frankenstein.  I added a screen shot of my iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator in portrait orientation to show you what I'm seeing.

Comment: Could you try clearing the data of your simulator and running again? Also, try clearing the derived data and clean the project before running again.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the DerivedData folder, executed "Product -> Clean Build Folder" in Xcode, deleted the app from the simulator, and tried again.  I'm still getting only 4 tabs.  The same thing is happening in other simulators (e.g., iPhone 8 Plus in portrait orientation).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you started with a default Single View app and then changed your class from:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

to:

```
class ViewController: UITabBarController {
```

which won't work.

Assuming that's the case:

- delete the View Controller from your Storyboard
- add a `UITabBarController`
- delete the two "default" view controllers that come with it
- set the Custom Class of the newly added tab bar controller to `ViewController`

That should do it.

Side note: I would change the class name...

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was using the "Single View App" template.  So I created a new project following your instructions, and they worked perfectly!  The only thing I had to add was to check the "Is Initial View Controller" checkbox in the Attributes inspector of the tab bar controller.  And you're also right about changing the class name.  But why didn't my initial program work?  If I use the original Main.storyboard, why does the operating system let me instantiate my own subclass of UIViewController, but not let me instantiate my own subclass of UITabBarController?

Comment: @MarkMeretzky - You cannot simply assign a custom class to an object. For example, if you write a `class MyImageView: UIImageView`, put a `UILabel` on your Storyboard, and then assign the Custom Class of that label to `MyImageView` you're going to have problems.